# Can't create a Database on Oracle 11g

Tags: windows, oracle

I'm new on Oracle and I'm trying to create a new database. I followed tutorials online but the problem seems to be in Windows and not in Oracle. 
I'm using the Oracle assistant to build my Database but when I arrive at the last stage and the assistant begin to configure all, there is an error (image attached).

From the message, seems that my user haven't the permission to read, write and execute anything from documents but it is not true. I gave full permission to my user and so I don't know why it stuck again here.

My system configuration is: 
 - Oracle 11g ver. 2 
 - Windows 7 Pro (64bit)

[image: error message]

Comment: You gave full permissions to which user - your own account, or the one that Oracle is running under? Seems like an odd location for the ADR base anyway; why not somewhere under `\Oracle`?

Comment: The one that Oracle is running under. I know the position is strange but I was a trouble when I installed the 64bit version of Oracle and I solved modifying some conf. files that was in documents. But I don't remember which files

Answer (score 1):

In a command line, run:

```
attrib C:\Users\Pierpaolo\Documents
```

If you see a capital R in the output, then the read-only attribute is set for that folder (which is the default setting for the Documents folder).

Either remove the read-only attribute from the folder (I do not know what this will mess up in Windows), or specify a different folder for diagnostic dest.
For the latter, on this screen, go to `All Initialization Parameters...`, and set the value of `diagnostic_dest` to a directory that has no read-only attribute set.

[image]